# How send result of each iteration of for loop to the html via flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, electron

I have python application which uses Electron.js as a gui and that program takes folder name from html and sends to python. In python scripts, it reads the each of photos and detect them.

But in each iteratation I cannot send them to the html.

## How can ı send the result of each photos to the html.

```
@app.route("/Multi", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def multiPlantAlaysis():
    if request.method == "GET":
        print("gete  griddd")
        return render_template("MultiGrapeAnalysis.html")

    if request.method == "POST":
        path = request.form["path"]

        data_path = os.path.join(path, '*g')
        files = glob.glob(data_path)
        data = []
        acc5 = []
        classes2 = []
        for f1 in files:
            img = cv2.imread(f1)
            name = str((f1))
            accuracies, classes = 
        PredictGrape(name,classifierGrape,ResultArrayGrape)

        return render_template("xyz.html", preds=accuracies,
                                   classes=json.dumps(classes )
```

It only sends one of them. I know that because of the return statement it does it. But is there a way of doing this ?

## Edit

I created an array, I added each result to arrays and return them with the html. However the problem is in that, if the images more then 20 in the folder gui waits approximately 1 minute. Therefore I need to pass each result to html. How can do this ?

Comment: Can you explain what `x` and `y` are in the last 2 lines? It's probably because your results are overwritten in the for loop? You can pass a list into render_template if that's what you are asking.

Comment: There is no problem, I have changed them last minute sory for the ambiguity. The problem is, it only sends the one result to the html.

Comment: I think `accuracies, classes` are replaced in each iteration of the for loop. That's why. But if you create a list of  `accuracies` and list of `classes`, you should be able to send them through `render_template`.

Comment: I did it, but still I have problem. Thank you for your comments.